# TypeError: $(...).easyAutocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, easyautocomplete

I am trying to follow jquery [easyAutocomplete docs](http://easyautocomplete.com/) and getting this error. I know this is a very common question and there have been asked a handful in SO. But none of them seems to erase my error. Here is my code

test.js

```
var options = {
  url: "places.json",
  getValue: "name",

  list: {
    match: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },

  theme: "square"
};

$("#textbox").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>test</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Location: <br />
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="enterlocation" id="textbox" />
      <button>enter</button>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script async src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

json:

```
[
  { "name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF" },
  { "name": "Aland Islands", "code": "AX" },
  { "name": "Albania", "code": "AL" },
  { "name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ" },
  { "name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS" }
]
```

Comment: You haven't included the easyautocomplete library in the page. It's not a standard jQuery method. See the 'getting started' section of the docs: http://easyautocomplete.com/guide

Comment: Include the easyautocomplete library in page and the error will be gone

Comment: Can you tell me how can I find the `path/to/` ? I am using ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [EasyAutocomplete guide](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide), it says:

> In order to use EasyAutocomplete, add these files in header section of
>   your page.
>
> ```
> <!-- JS file -->
> <script src="path/to/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script> 
>
> <!-- CSS file -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/easy-autocomplete.min.css"> 
>
> <!-- Additional CSS Themes file - not required-->
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/easy-autocomplete.themes.min.css">
> ```
>
> Remember to include jQuery file. You can download library from [the
>   jQuery website](http://jquery.com/). Best practice is to use CDN server:
>
> ```
> <!-- Using jQuery with a CDN -->
> <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
> ```

Based on this, you'll need to include `jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js` after jQuery and before your own code. You should also include `easy-autocomplete.min.css`.

Comment: @ProteetiProva Since you're using CDNs for the other stuff, you can probably use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.min.css`.